# Use VBA to update AllowEdits property in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm very new to Access, VBA, and Database management in general. I'm currently creating forms for a database I just finished creating to allow other users to interact with the database. One of the forms essentially acts as a list (but is not the access "list" insert), and is just a datasheet subform within my form. I have it set to default to not allow edits, but I want the end user to be able to override this, should they want to make edits to multiple records without opening an edit form over and over. I do have Create and Delete records disabled, and would like to keep them that way, but I'm trying to use VBA on a button click to allow editing with the subform, but I've gotten various issues with the different things that I've tried:

As a side note, "subfrmEquipmentDatasheet" is the list within the overall form, which is called "EquipmentListF" and the actual datasheet viewbox is called "EquipList"

I've tried a few things but for the most part the error messages have been similar. I've gotten "cannot find the referenced form" (I literally copied and pasted the name so its spelled right), and a message that essentially said this property can't be changed on this content box. I'm pretty sure the issue is just me referencing incorrectly, as I said with the former it's spelled right, and with the latter, I tried the Forms!subfrm!ContentName formatting to reference it, and while it was able to find it that way, I don't think its the proper way to reference it to change that property.

```
Private Sub UpdateRecords_Click()

    Forms("subfrmEquipmentDatasheet").AllowEdits = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If the instruction applies to the form containing the code, you can use  ’Me.properry’

Comment: This gives me no error messages, but still won't allow me to edit it.

Comment: If button is on main form, need to reference subform through the subform container control. If container is named "subfrmEquipmentDatasheet", try: `Me.subfrmEquipmentDatasheet.Form.AllowEdits = True`. Do not change `Form` to anything else. I always name container differently from the object it holds, like: `ctrEquip`.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

In response to the naming convention used, I've done that for everything except controls, it sounds stupid but as I said, I'm very new to this language and I thought of the subform as the control, without considering that it had a control within itself. I'm gonna go through and fix every instance of that once I get everything up and running. I want to have a working copy in the shop before I make changes that really only improve Quality of Life for the developer. 

Thanks again!